# Upload de imagem fora da pasta do LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, upload, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida, é possivel eu fazer upload de uma imagem no laravel para fora da pasta do projeto?
Pois estou com um projeto que a pasta do site é fora da pasta do laravel e preciso exibir imagens upadas no laravel neste site.

```
\WWW\
     DESTINO_IMAGEM\
     LARAVEL\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não cheguei a testar, mas acredito que você possa criar um novo disco com o `root`apontando para essa pasta fora do laravel.

Os discos funcionam como forma de você informar como fará seu armazenamento, podendo ser no sistema de arquivo local (usando `local` como seu `driver`) ou mesmo na nuvem (ex: aws s3)

**Como configurar**

As configurações dos discos estão no arquivo `config/filesystems` e basta você adicionar mais um item ao array `disks`. Um exemplo para o seu caso seria:

```
'disks' => [
    ...
    'pasta_externa' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/var/www/DESTINO_IMAGEM'
    ]
]
```